# Is this the right notation for points in a square or rectangle?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I have a function $f$ that calculates a vector for a given point, both in 2D (that's to say $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, (x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$, I guess).

I plotted the resulting field of vectors limiting both x and y to the interval $[-10, 10]$, thus giving me a square around the origin. How do I put this in the set notation? I guess I could say I plotted in $\{(x, y) \in [-10; 10]^2\}$. Is that correct?

What if one dimension used a different interval (creating a rectangle)? What would be the right symbol between both intervals? Could I write $\{(x, y) \in [-10; 10]\times [-20; 5] \}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$H = \{(x,y): (x,y) \in [-10,10] \times [-10,10]\}$$

Comment: Would you say the shorthand notation of $^2$ is invalid if the intervals are the same?

Comment: Nah, definitely valid.

Comment: $[-10,10]^2$ is valid.  It might be ambiguous or unclear in another context.  But it is valid.  However H = {$z|z \in$ G} is redundant and pointlessly over nested.

Answer (score 2):

$[a,b] \times [c,d]$, I think, would be recognized as the set you mean.

In my opinion, writing $H = \{(x,y)| (x,y) \in [a,b] \times [c,d]\}$ is redundant.  If $(x,y)$ is in $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ then why the heck don't you your just write $H = [a,b]\times [c,d]$?????  After all if you wrote $H = \{x|x \in \mathbb R\}$ that'd be seen as ridiculous; $H = \mathbb R$ fercripesake!

The only reason to put it in set notation is for clarity/definition as $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ might not be clear in meaning or might not be known to a novice.  In which case $H = \{(x,y)| (x,y) \in [a,b] \times [c,d]\}$ does nothing to add to the clarity.

Why not just write $H = \{(x,y)| a \le x \le b; c \le y \le d\}$.  That's perfectly clear and legit.  Or $H = [a,b]\times [c,d] = \{(x,y)| a \le x \le b; c \le y \le d\}$ can be seen as a definition.

But to answer your question $H = [a,b]\times[c,d] := \{(x,y)| a \le x \le b; c \le y \le d\}$ is acceptable and standard notation.

Comment: Things like this are a matter of opinion. I didn't know people cared so much. I can delete my response if it's really that repulsive.

Comment: "repulsive" is too strong an overstatement. it was in response to the OP not you.you were the accepted answer. Please do not delete. [a,b] x [c,d] is acceptable notation as we point out. My point is if you use set notation then *use* it. i)H = {x| x in G} means H=G.  Always. so don't pussyfoot and ii)H={some set} form is for the sake of *definition*. If you use set notation you can use it to define things; *do* so. "What is the notation for the set of all real numbers whose cube root has third decimal digit = 7?"  Answer: H = {x|cube root of x has 7 as its third decial digit}

Comment: I just think at all times we should remain as professional as possible on this site. I understand what you are saying now and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "*why the heck don't you your just write H=[a,b]×[c,d]H=[a,b]×[c,d]?*" because I don't need to give the set a name, but I do want to use the variables x and y, because they are used previously. I never liked the notation with inequalities and prefer the interval notation. I just want to say in what area I made the plot.

Comment: @null point taken but that's kind of my point.  If x, and why were used explicitly then they are not the generic (x,y) in {(x,y)|(x,y) \in [a,b][,cd]}.  Just say "I plotted all the (x,y) in [a,b]x[c,d]".  To say "I plotted all the (x,y) such that (x,y) were in the set of all (w,y) where (w,y) were in [a,b]x[c,d]" is pointlessly nested.  You could say "I plotted all the points in {(x,y)| x in [a,b] and y in [c,d]}" if you don't like inequalities but I think you can refer to notation "I plotted all the points in [a,b]x[c,d]" and and assume it will be understood.

Comment: I think my premise that the set notation should be used for this was wrong. I think that last version in your comment looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too harshly.  Set notation is fine.  Basically you want to say "I plotted all (x,y) where x,y in [a,b]" but to describe the area you want to say "I plotted all (x,y) where (x,y) in the rectangle formed by [a,b] cross [a,b]" and "I plotted all (x,y) where (x,y) in [a,b]^2 and gee, can I say that?" to "I plotted {(x,y)|(x,y) in [a,b]^2}" and in this step by step reasoning it's easy to lose sight the "Gee,  I plotted [a,b]^2... that's it... that's all I need to say"  So it's not unreasonable to do what you did.  It's just... less succinct than it could be.